# How many times can I activate Windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-7, license, msdn

I have an MSDN version of Windows 7 Enterprise.

I think I saw somewhere that this version can be installed on multiple computers with the same serial number. Is that correct? How many times can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN licensing is a tricky model. Each MSDN license is for a single person, and that single person can install the software on as many machines as needed for development purposes. If you perform any non-development actions on computers with MSDN licenses, you are violating the terms of the license agreement.

Quote from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/cc150618.aspx):

> Many MSDN subscribers use a computer
>   for mixed use—both design,
>   development, testing, and
>   demonstration of your programs (the
>   use allowed under the MSDN
>   subscription license) and some other
>   use.  Using the software in any other
>   way, such as for doing email, playing
>   games, or editing a document is
>   another use and is not covered by the
>   MSDN subscription license.

While there is no technical limitation preventing from using an MSDN license as a retail copy, doing so can get you into trouble with microsoft. MSDN licenses are for testing labs to allow a software developer to cheaply test their programs on a wide array of hardware.

If you are not a software developer, then you should not use this license. If you are, then you should read the terms of the license agreement when you purchase this license.

Comment: Yes to clarify I am a developer, and was wondering if I can use that same serial key on several of my own computers and/or virtual machines.

Comment: From what I have read, you can. After the first few, you'll have to give Microsoft a call to activate it. The License says you can so there shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 Enterprise is only sold using volume licensing. Therefore, every Windows 7 Enterprise product key is a volume license key.

The number of installations you may use is determined by how many licenses you purchase.

Comment: With MSDN they didn't really tell me how many "licenses" it included.

Comment: Ah, I missed the mention of MSDN. As Doltknuckle said, MSDN allows you to use it on as many machines as you need but for development purposes only.